# importing lib failed (python) after installing lib with pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Hi i wanted to try out vs code for writing python. previously I used to use spyder and I had no problem with that but in vs code after I installed a lib using pip. I can't use the lib and I get an import error. actually the problem is global when I use pip in my terminal to install a lib I get requirements already satisfied msg but after importing it in my code I still get the import error!

Comment: Try running `pip uninstall lib` and then installing it again.

Comment: Try `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` - this should get you a clean pip envnironment

Comment: @rv.kvetch 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I get this msg while trying to execute your cmd

Comment: @SamMatzko i did how said but now when i am trying again to install lib i get a long cryptic error msg in red:ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KHATAM RAYANE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\KHATAM RAYANE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper .......... and the error goes on

Comment: What version of python are you using? Have you tried `pip3 install...`?

Comment: @SamMatzko it worked i installed lib once more but the same issue as before python can't find the library    do i need to reinstall my python?

Comment: @Asrapian: I was commenting in a similar question and other users suggested using `python -m pip install <package>`. Remember: you *must* use the same Python version for installing that you use to run the program. So if you use `python3` to run your program, use `python3` to install the module. If you use `python` to run your program, then use `python` to install. Otherwise, the program won't recognise that the module is installed, because you'll be running the other version of Python!

Comment: @SamMatzko wow your solution worked! why is it what is the difference between ur command and this pip install <package> ?

Comment: @Asrapian: `pip3` is specific to python 3, I think, so it by default installs packages into python 3. An even better way to be sure that you're installing using the right python version: `python3 -m pip install...`. This *guarantees* that pip is installing in the right python version. Note that this only works in python 3 (at least on my Linux).

Comment: @SamMatzko great! i keep that in mind thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Which python interpreter you selected in the VSCode?

[image]

It looks like you have installed the packages into the global python environment, but in the VSCode you have not selected that environment.

Comment: hey thanks i have taken your advice and tried to solve the issue but still no result i dont use a virtual environment but i have multiple versions of python(python.org and conda version) i tried to firgure out maybe this was the problem but still i have installed the same library in both python version but when i am using the library on both python version i get no module found error